1980/1990 TV show taking place both in the real world and inside a computer
I remember a tv series about of the 80/90 where the story was located in the real world but also inside a PC and there was monsters like dinosaurs or robots and a team against the evil of about 2-3 young boys and girls and a nice young female protagonist, blonde i think.  

Oh, I remember that show, at least I think you're talking about the one that aired here in Germany as well, some time during the 90's (along Power Rangers and others):
Superhuman Samurai Syber-Squad
A few images and the intro can be found in this list of "Power Ranger Rip-Offs", although there's no blonde girl.
I remember watching it and it was quite entertaining, also to note that they worked a lot with bright/neon colors as well as transparent parts to model their "cyberspace".
If that's not the show, just look through the other articles, although I'm quite sure this is the right one.
